# Timer that doesn't want to start with GPIO button

Tags: python, pyqt

I have a timer that I can start with either a start/stop button on the screen or two GPIO buttons.

The screen start/stop buttons works fine.

The GPIO buttons does not work all the time. I can see the "Start" getting printed in the terminal window, but the timer doesn't start. If I click the button several times, it might start. If I ALT-TAB, it starts.

What am I missing here?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(23, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

class Timer(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Timer, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):


# Setup font
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily('Lucida')
        font.setFixedPitch(True)
        font.setPointSize(30)
        fontPalette = QtGui.QPalette()

# Background image
        oImage = QtGui.QImage("bg.jpg")
        sImage = oImage
        sImage = oImage.scaledToWidth(1920)
        palette = QtGui.QPalette()
        palette.setBrush(10, QtGui.QBrush(sImage))
        self.setPalette(palette)        

# LCD display
        self.lcd = QtGui.QLCDNumber(self)
        self.lcd.setMode(1)
        self.lcd.setSegmentStyle(1)
        self.lcd.setDigitCount(8)
        self.lcd.resize(1520, 1080)
        self.lcd.setGeometry(200, 0, 1520, 1080)
        self.lcd.setFrameShape(0)
        self.lcd.display("00:00:00")

# Setup the timer
        self.lcdTimer = QtCore.QTime(0,0,0,0)
        self.lcd.display(self.lcdTimer.toString('mm:ss:zzz')[:8])        

        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.updateLCD)

# Quit button
        self.btnQuit = QtGui.QPushButton('Quit', self)
        self.btnQuit.clicked.connect(self.quitTimer)
        self.btnQuit.move(50, 1005)  

# Start button
        btnStart = QtGui.QPushButton('Start', self)
        btnStart.move(750, 1005)
        btnStart.clicked.connect(self.startBtn)

# Stop button
        btnStop = QtGui.QPushButton('Stop', self)
        btnStop.move(850, 1005)
        btnStop.clicked.connect(self.stopBtn)

# Reset button
        self.btnReset = QtGui.QPushButton('Reset', self)
        self.btnReset.move(150, 1005)
        self.btnReset.clicked.connect(self.buttonClicked)


# Setup the window
        self.setWindowTitle('Timer')
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 1920, 1080)
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.show()


    def updateLCD(self):
        telapsed = self.lcdTimer.elapsed()
        msecs = telapsed % 1000
        secs = int(telapsed / 1000)
        mins = (secs / 60) % 60
        secs = secs % 60

        self.lcd.display(str(mins).zfill(2) + ":" + str(secs).zfill(2) + ":" + str(msecs)[:2].zfill(2))
        time.sleep(0.05)

    def buttonClicked(self):
        sender = self.sender()
        if sender.text() == "Reset":
            self.lcdTimer = QtCore.QTime(0,0,0,0)
            self.lcd.display(self.lcdTimer.toString('mm:ss:zzz')[:8])

    def startBtn(self, channel):
        print("Start")
        self.lcdTimer.start()
        self.timer.start()

    def stopBtn(self, channel):
        print("Stop")
        self.timer.stop()

    def quitTimer(self):
        GPIO.cleanup()
        QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance().quit()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Timer()

    GPIO.add_event_detect(18, GPIO.FALLING, callback=ex.startBtn, bouncetime=500)
    GPIO.add_event_detect(23, GPIO.FALLING, callback=ex.stopBtn, bouncetime=500)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

EDIT:

I got the counter to update in the gui, but now I can't get the start button to restart cause it's connected to the wrong start.

The comments that has ### are the ones that can be changed to get them to work either with timer updates the gui or start button can restart the timer.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
from PyQt4.QtGui import QWidget, QFont, QPalette, QImage, QBrush, QLCDNumber, QPushButton, QApplication, QTextEdit, QScrollArea, QTextCursor, QColor
from PyQt4.QtCore import QThread, Qt, QCoreApplication, QTime, QTimer, SIGNAL, pyqtSignal, QObject

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(23, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

class handleTimer(QObject):

    timerChanged = pyqtSignal(str, name = 'timerChanged')

    def __init__(self):
        QObject.__init__(self)
        self._isRunning = False
        self.timerString = "00:00:00"
        self.timerReset()

    def timerStart(self, channel=0):
        if not self._isRunning and self.timerString != "00:00:00":
            print("-Reset")
            self.timerReset()
        elif not self._isRunning:
            print("-Start")
            self._isRunning = True
            self.timer2.start()
            self.lcdTimer2.start()


    def stop(self, channel=0):
        print("-Stop")
        if self._isRunning:
            self.updateNumber()
            self.timer2.stop()
            self.lcdTimer2.restart()      
            self._isRunning = False

    def timerReset(self):
        print("-Reset")
        self.lcdTimer2 = QTime(0,0,0,0)
        self.timer2 = QTimer(self)
        self.timer2.setInterval(50)
        self.timer2.timeout.connect(self.updateNumber)
        self.updateNumber()

    def updateNumber(self):
        if self._isRunning:
            self.telapsed = self.lcdTimer2.elapsed()
            self.msecs = self.telapsed % 1000
            self.secs = int(self.telapsed / 1000)
            self.mins = (self.secs / 60) % 60
            self.secs = self.secs % 60
            self.timerString = str(self.mins).zfill(2) + ":" + str(self.secs).zfill(2) + ":" + str(self.msecs)[:2].zfill(2)
        else:
            self.timerString = "00:00:00"

        self.timerChanged.emit(self.timerString)
        print(self.timerString)



class Timer(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Timer, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):


# Setup font
        font = QFont()
        font.setFamily('Lucida')
        font.setFixedPitch(True)
        font.setPointSize(30)
        fontPalette = QPalette()

# Background image
        oImage = QImage("bg.jpg")
        sImage = oImage
        sImage = oImage.scaledToWidth(1920)
        palette = QPalette()
        palette.setBrush(10, QBrush(sImage))
        self.setPalette(palette)        

# LCD display
        self.lcd = QLCDNumber(self)
        self.lcd.setMode(1)
        self.lcd.setSegmentStyle(1)
        self.lcd.setDigitCount(8)
        self.lcd.resize(1020, 1080)
        self.lcd.setGeometry(200, 0, 1020, 1080)
        self.lcd.setFrameShape(0)
        self.lcd.display("00:00:00")

# Setup thread
        self.simulThread = QThread()
###        self.simulThread.start()
        self.simulRunner = handleTimer()
        self.simulRunner.moveToThread(self.simulThread)
        self.simulRunner.timerChanged.connect(self.updateLCD)


# Quit button
        self.btnQuit = QPushButton('Quit', self)
        self.btnQuit.clicked.connect(self.quitTimer)
        self.btnQuit.move(50, 1005)

# Reset button
        self.btnReset = QPushButton('Reset', self)
        self.btnReset.move(150, 1005)
        self.btnReset.clicked.connect(self.simulRunner.timerReset)

# Start button
        self.btnStart = QPushButton('Start', self)
        self.btnStart.move(750, 1005)
###        self.btnStart.clicked.connect(self.simulRunner.timerStart)
        self.btnStart.clicked.connect(self.simulThread.start)   ###

        self.simulThread.started.connect(self.simulRunner.timerStart)   ###
###        GPIO.add_event_detect(18, GPIO.FALLING, callback=self.simulRunner.timerStart, bouncetime=1000)
        GPIO.add_event_detect(18, GPIO.FALLING, callback=self.simulThread.start, bouncetime=1000)   ###

# Stop button
        self.btnStop = QPushButton('Stop', self)
        self.btnStop.move(850, 1005)
        self.btnStop.clicked.connect(lambda: self.simulRunner.stop())

#        self.simulThread.finished.connect(self.simulRunner.timerDelete)
        GPIO.add_event_detect(23, GPIO.FALLING, callback=lambda x: self.simulRunner.stop(), bouncetime=1000)

# Setup the window
        self.setWindowTitle('Timer')
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 1220, 1080)
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)

    def updateLCD(self, val):
        self.lcd.display(val)
        self.lcd.update()

    def quitTimer(self):
        GPIO.cleanup()
        QCoreApplication.instance().quit()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Timer()
    ex.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: You have not set the time interval of the timer. use `self.timer.setInterval(1000)` or do it when you start the timer: `self.timer.start(1000)`

Comment: That somewhat helped. The counter is running in the background, but the GUI doesn't start/update until I click that window. Very odd.

Answer (score 0):

It seemed to be that add_event_detect was blocking the thread, or something like that.

There's probably an easier solution, but this works at least.

I put the callback for add_event_detect in it's own thread and a custom signal for what button that is pressed.
In the thread that has the timer, I put a listener for what button that is pressed.

The code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import threading
from PyQt4.QtGui import QWidget, QFont, QPalette, QImage, QBrush, QLCDNumber, QPushButton, QApplication, QTextEdit, QScrollArea, QTextCursor, QColor, QMainWindow
from PyQt4.QtCore import QThread, Qt, QCoreApplication, QTime, QTimer, pyqtSignal, QObject

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(23, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)


class handleButtons(QObject):

    button = pyqtSignal(str, name = 'button')

    def __init__(self):
        QObject.__init__(self)

    def buttonListener(self, channel):
        if channel == 18:
            self.button.emit("start")
        elif channel == 23:
            self.button.emit("stop")


class handleTimer(QObject):

    timerChanged = pyqtSignal(str, name = 'timerChanged')
    finished = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self):
        QObject.__init__(self)
        self._isRunning = False
        self.timerString = "00:00:00"

        self.timerReset()

    def pushButton(self, button):
        if button == "start":
            self.timerStart()
        elif button == "stop":
            self.stop()

    def timerStart(self, channel=0):
        if not self._isRunning and self.timerString != "00:00:00":
            self.timerReset()
        elif not self._isRunning:
            self._isRunning = True
            self.timer2.start(50)
            self.lcdTimer2.start()


    def stop(self, channel=0):
        if self._isRunning:
            self.updateNumber()
            self.timer2.stop()
            self.lcdTimer2.restart()      
            self._isRunning = False
            self.finished.emit()

    def timerReset(self):
        self.lcdTimer2 = QTime(0,0,0,0)
        self.timer2 = QTimer()
        self.timer2.setInterval(50)
        self.timer2.timeout.connect(self.updateNumber)
        self.updateNumber()

    def updateNumber(self):
        if self._isRunning:
            self.telapsed = self.lcdTimer2.elapsed()
            self.msecs = self.telapsed % 1000
            self.secs = int(self.telapsed / 1000)
            self.mins = (self.secs / 60) % 60
            self.secs = self.secs % 60
            self.timerString = str(self.mins).zfill(2) + ":" + str(self.secs).zfill(2) + ":" + str(self.msecs)[:2].zfill(2)
        else:
            self.timerString = "00:00:00"

        self.timerChanged.emit(self.timerString)



class Timer(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

# Setup thread
        self.timerThread = QThread()

        self.timerRunner = handleTimer()
        self.timerRunner.moveToThread(self.timerThread)
        self.timerRunner.timerChanged.connect(self.updateLCD)

        self.timerThread.started.connect(self.timerRunner.timerReset)

        self.buttonRunner = handleButtons()
        self.buttonRunner.moveToThread(self.timerThread)
        self.buttonRunner.button.connect(self.timerRunner.pushButton)

        self.timerThread.start()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

# Setup font
        font = QFont()
        font.setFamily('Lucida')
        font.setFixedPitch(True)
        font.setPointSize(30)
        fontPalette = QPalette()

# Background image
        oImage = QImage("bg.jpg")
        sImage = oImage
        sImage = oImage.scaledToWidth(1920)
        palette = QPalette()
        palette.setBrush(10, QBrush(sImage))
        self.setPalette(palette)        

# LCD display
        self.lcd = QLCDNumber(self)
        self.lcd.setMode(1)
        self.lcd.setSegmentStyle(1)
        self.lcd.setDigitCount(8)
        self.lcd.resize(1020, 1080)
        self.lcd.setGeometry(200, 0, 1020, 1080)
        self.lcd.setFrameShape(0)
        self.lcd.display("00:00:00")

# Quit button
        self.btnQuit = QPushButton('Quit', self)
        self.btnQuit.clicked.connect(self.quitTimer)
        self.btnQuit.move(50, 1005)

# Start button
        GPIO.add_event_detect(18, GPIO.FALLING, callback=self.buttonRunner.buttonListener, bouncetime=1000)

# Stop button
        GPIO.add_event_detect(23, GPIO.FALLING, callback=lambda x: self.timerRunner.stop(), bouncetime=1000)

# Setup the window
        self.setWindowTitle('Timer')
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 1220, 1080)
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)

    def updateLCD(self, val):
        self.lcd.display(val)

    def quitTimer(self):
        GPIO.cleanup()
        QCoreApplication.instance().quit()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Timer()
    main.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```